# How to run Cucumber tests with 'mvn test'

Tags: maven, testing, kotlin, cucumber

Note that I'm using Kotlin.
Also note that I have a multi-modules application.

I succeed in running Cucumber tests from the IDE by running the `RunCukesTest.kt` class.

My problem is that when I run the command `mvn test`, The `RunCukesTest.kt` doesn't seems to run, and none `.feature` is tested.

I'm not sure if I need to configure the `maven-surefire-plugin` in order to make it work.

**domain-pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>smart-notes</artifactId>
        <groupId>xxx</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>domain</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <cucumber.version>4.4.0</cucumber.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**parent-pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>domain</module>
        <module>infra</module>
    </modules>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>smart-notes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>smart-notes</name>
    <description>Take quick smart notes</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.40</kotlin.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.4.2</junit-jupiter.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**RunCukesTest.kt**

```java
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(Cucumber::class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = ["pretty"],
        features = ["classpath:features"],
        glue = ["classpath:acceptance.stepdefs"])
class RunCukesTest
```

**some-feature.feature**

```java
Feature: Is it friday yet

  Scenario: my scenario
    Given today is Sunday
    When I ask whether it's Friday yet
    Then I should be told "Nope"
```

**Maven build logs**

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ domain ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.209 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-23T16:46:35+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Architecture**

- src

  - test

    - kotlin

      - acceptance

        - RunCukesTest.kt
        - stepdefs

          - StepDefsTest.kt
    - resources

      - features

        - some-feature.feature

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Refer to this guide - https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/. Switch to the kotlin tab at the top

Comment: Thank you, I've had already followed this tutorial, even after adding the kotlin-maven-plugin and maven-compiler-plugin + configurations, it still fails.
I have done 'mvn **clean** test' (in order to regenerate compiled classes) and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the issue.

I've had to do `mvn clean test` in order to re-generate the compiled tests so that maven can find them with the `*Test.class` regex.

the most important attribute is the `<testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>` inside the `<build>` section to tell Maven to look into this directory in order to find the tests to execute.

Here's my two cleaned-up poms :

**parent-pom.xml**

```xml
    <properties>
        <kotlin.version>1.3.40</kotlin.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.4.2</junit-jupiter.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**domain-pom.xml**

```xml
    <properties>
        <cucumber.version>4.4.0</cucumber.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**logs** :

```java
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running RunCukesTest
juin 25, 2019 12:01:59 AM cucumber.runtime.java.ObjectFactoryLoader loadSingleObjectFactory
AVERTISSEMENT: Use deprecated reflections to load ObjectFactory.
Feature: Is it friday yet

  Scenario: my scenario                # features/some-feature.feature:3
    Given today is Sunday              # StepDefs.today_is_Sunday()
    When I ask whether it's Friday yet # StepDefs.i_ask_whether_it_s_Friday_yet()
    Then I should be told "Nope"       # StepDefs.i_should_be_told(String)

1 Scenarios (1 passed)
3 Steps (3 passed)
0m0,245s

[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.251 s - in RunCukesTest
```